# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file while looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

Hi I am facing I/O error while looping file execution. The code prompt 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.' while running. Does anyone have any idea while says operation on closed as I am opening new while looping? Many thanks

code below:

```
with open('inputlist.csv', 'r') as f:  #input list reading
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    queries2Google = reader
print(queries2Google)

def QGN(query2Google):
    s = '"'+query2Google+'"' #Keywords for query, to solve the + for space
    s = s.replace(" ","+")
    date = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) #timestamp
    filename =query2Google+"_"+date+"_"+'SearchNews.csv' #csv filename
    f = open(filename,"wb")   #open output file

    pass

    df = np.reshape(df,(-1,3))
    itemnum,col=df.shape
    itemnum=str(itemnum)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['Title','URL','Brief'])
    print("Done! "+itemnum+" pieces found.")

    df1.to_csv(filename, index=False,encoding='utf-8')
    f.close()

    return

for query2Google in queries2Google:
    QGN(query2Google) #output should be multiple files
```

Comment: Can we get a line number?

Answer (score 0):

[`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) closes the file that you are trying to read once it it is done. So you are opening file, making a csv reader, and then closing the underlying file and then trying to read from it. See more about file i/o [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Solution is to do all of your work on your `queries2Google` reader INSIDE the with statement:

```
with open('inputlist.csv', 'r') as f:  #input list reading
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for q2g in reader:
        QGN(q2g)
```

Some additional stuff:

That `pass` isn't doing anything and you should probably be using `with` again inside the `QGN` function since the file is opened and closed in there. Python doesn't need empty returns. You also don't seem to even be using `f` in the `QGN` function.